# Accessing a printer from Ubuntu client to Windows server

Tags: ubuntu, printer, windows-server-2008-r2, sharing

I installed a Windows server 2008 R2 and an Ubuntu 12.04 and could connect the Ubuntu to the server using likewise. The FTP is also set up. I did depoly the printer in server and another client, a Windows 7 PC can access it. (upon double click I see the print queue). However, I can't get my Ubuntu to see it, no matter how much I Google-d for the answer. Any ideas?